# Surjectivity of multiplication maps with respect to pullback

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Given a morphism $f: Y \to X$ and a globally generated line bundle $\mathcal L$ on $X$ such that $H^0(X,\mathcal L) \otimes H^0(X,\mathcal L) \to H^0(X,\mathcal L \otimes \mathcal L)$ is surjective.

Which kind of assumptions on $Y,X,f$ and $\mathcal L$ are sufficient to guarantee the same holds for $f^*\mathcal L$, i.e.
$H^0(Y,f^*\mathcal L) \otimes H^0(Y,f^*\mathcal L) \to H^0(Y,f^*\mathcal L \otimes f^*\mathcal L)$
is surjective?

I am particularly interested in the case that $X$ is the projective space over a field, $f$ a closed immersion and $\mathcal L = \mathcal O(1)$.

I know that it should be sufficient to require the embedding to be projectively normal in that case. Are there weaker assumptions?

Comment: You should have a look at Mumford's paper "Varieties Defined by Quadratic Equations".  It is both famous and readily available.  It certainly contains interesting information on your question.  It may even satisfy your question.